# Call getsubscription() function in email template module

Tags: magento

I need to insert aheadworx SARP SUBSCRIPTION ID in email template module

how to call $this->getSubscription()->getId() which is in aw_sarp module in the below page

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Regards,
seb

Answer (score 3):

To get the subscription variables or details use the following things :

Templates variables/methods

```
subscription.id - ID of subscription
subscription.customer_name - name of the customer who purchased subscription
subscription.getCustomerUrl() - URL for customer to view subscription
subscription.getAdminUrl() - URL for admin to view subscription
subscription.next_delivery_date - next delivery date
subscription.next_payment_date - next payment date
subscription.first_delivery_date - first delivery date
subscription.customer_email - customer email address
subscription.products_text - products with quantity included in subscription
```

For more informtion kindly visit to : http://confluence.aheadworks.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3342482#Subscriptions&RecurringPayments-Templatesvariables/methods

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this code;

`$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);`

And for retrieving the id;

`$subscriber->getId()`